# R packages in `/usr/` vs. `~/R/` , specifically within the `r2u` framework

Tags: r, ubuntu, linux-mint, apt, r2u

I am relatively new to Linux (currently using Linux Mint 21.2). Looking at other SO posts, it seems common that the `R` command `.libPaths()` returns 1-3 paths, all sub-directories of `/usr/` (namely, [2]-[4] below). However, when I run `.libPaths()`, I get the following:

```
[1] "/home/<user>/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                   
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                         
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

I have not seen many people list a home directory in their `.libPaths`. This is fine, but I would think this would be more common, since it's mentioned in the [CRAN documentation on R packages in Ubuntu](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html#pathways-to-r-packages):

> In order to find packages, R looks at the variables R_LIBS_USER and R_LIBS_SITE. On Debian and Ubuntu, R_LIBS_USER is set in /etc/R/Renviron to
>
> ```
> R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/$platform-library/3.5'}
> ```
>
> where $platform is something like ‘x86_64-pc-linux-gnu’ and depending on the version of R installed.

I have also just installed [`r2u`](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) for installing R package binaries rather than building them from source. However, now it seems there is a discrepancy which worries me:

- RStudio reports that all packages are up to date
- Mint's Update Manager (`apt`-based) says there are 113 R packages which need to be updated

**So, what is my question?**

1. Any help in understanding the packages in `~/R/` versus the other `/usr/` spaces would be helpful.
2. Should I be worried that I have two completely R package libraries? Is there a way to safely merge them?
3. Is there a way to omit the R package updates from my Update Manager GUI? I don't really want the constant notifications of R-package updates.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Recall that `r2u`, especially when used with `bspm` gives a view on packages know to _both_ `apt` and `R`.  But when the `.libPaths()` starts in your home directory, only R knows those packages.  We have helper functions to find 'shadowed packages' in both Inaki's package `bspm` and in my general 'misc functions' package `dang`.  Start with that, and see some prior discussions at the repo.

Comment: If you want to use R _without_ such a directory below `~/R/` aka `/home/<user>/R/` you could do so by setting `R_LIBS_USER=""` in file `~/.Renviron` (or equivalently in any other startup file setting environment variables).  The `.libPaths()` will report only what are now positions 2 to 4 for you.

Comment: As for your questions:  1) and 2) have been discussed _for years_, for example on the `r-sig-debian` list.  Personally speaking, I have used R for decades and almost never have `~/R/` but "preferences differ".  Ultimately for you to decide.  As for 3) if you are referring to the RStudio GUI I believe there may be a toggle.   And lastly: all these questions are great!  It's a good and big topic and there are many ways to go about it.  The devil is always in the detail and the little tradeoffs.